# Parse Error Where Nothing Is Wrong

Tags: javascript, parsing, syntax-error

I'm making a mobile site using Dashcode to help me creating better UIs, but the problem is that I'm getting a strange Parse Error on my code, where nothing is wrong... This is the code:

```
function get_currency(from, to) {
    var XMLHttp;  // Create the Ajax handler
    XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=" + from + to + "=X";

    XMLHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
            /* Once the server has completed its tasks display the result */
            var response = XMLHttp.responseText;
            var parsed_reply = response.split(',');

            document.getElementById('txtAmount').value = parsed_reply[1];
    }
    XMLHttp.send(null);
}

function btConvert_Click(event)
{
    get_currency("BRL", "USD");
}
```

The error is occurring(According to the debugger) at the line 209(the last line of the code), which is the `}` a the end of this code that I gave. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing a closing `}` for your onreadstatechange handler, causing the parser to puke at the end of the script. Given the indentation, it's the closing } for the `if(XMLHttp.readyState...)` check

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `}`

Based on your spacing, you haven't closed the `{` from

```
if(XMLHttp.readyState == 4) {
```